# TSQL - same query is slow on one server but very fast on another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

This query

SELECT MAX(ID) FROM GeoArea

is very fast on a production server (16Gb RAM). It executes within 1 second.

But it is very slow on a test server (3Gb RAM). It takes more than 10 minutes (stil in progress!).

Database is the same. SQL Server version is the same.

The table has 2 million rows.
Why is it slow on a test server? I thought it is just a cluster index scan.

UPDATE

SQL restart did not help.
I've copied the production DB to the test server and it solved the problem.

Comment: Your hard disk can have different speed. Try to rebuild indexes and satistics.

Comment: Is it really SQL Server that's hogging the testmachine? Do you have other services running there? Can you post an execution plan? How about retrying a second time after the cache had a chance to fill? Are there other statements running at the same time on that machine? Is your statement blocked by those? The list why it's slower/faster actually is pretty endless...

Comment: thats a huge difference in RAM size, 3 GB is *very* little as a lot of that is filled with the overhead of the system

Answer (score 2):

could be (not limited to)

- purely hardware related (RAID in production, remote SAN-solution in test)
- rivaling activities on the same harddisk/RAM/CPU/table, maybe a deadlock, maybe uncommited transactions still open
- missing indexes (i know you said so, but is it *really* the same database?)

Answer (score 2):

10 minutes and it is still running?
Are you sure it is still running?
If ID is a clustered index and that table has 2 million rows then something is wrong.
1 second to 10 seconds is a big difference.
1 second to more than 10 minutes is more than hardware or indexes or statistics.

You possible have a lock on that table.
Try:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM GeoArea with (nolock)
```

If that does not fix it restart SQL.